Disk Partioning advice
This is the output from fdisk of my disk:
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xde067a1e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 717844479 717842432 342.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    717844480 718893055   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       718895102 976771071 257875970   123G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       718895104 976771071 257875968   123G 83 Linux

The Linux OS that I'm currently using is on sda5
I want to install a new Linux OS on sda1 and be able to dual boot between the one on sda5 and the new one on sda1.
I've tried installing a new OS, but 'bottled out' when I wasn't offered the option to install it on sda1!
I know just enough about disk partitioning to know that unless I'm very careful, I could lose the lot!
I'd welcome some advice, please.
Jim

Most mainstream distros have installers with a manual partitioning option where you'd select (and format, losing all the data in said partition) sda1 for root and select (DON'T format) sda2 as the ESP (EFI System Partition). Doing so it'll result in a dual-boot system with your current OS.

What OS are you trying to install? Different OSs have different installer GUIs (Ubiquity, Calamares). As mentioned, they have advanced options for partitioning management. Nonetheless, always backup before manipulating partitions.

I think the first piece of advice I would offer is: make a full backup, and test it to ensure that it's complete and viable.  That should take a lot of the fear and possible downside out of your experimenting.


I'd welcome some advice


first back up your data from that disk if you value it.

what you are playing around with... knowing just enough about disk partitioning the risk is high you might mess up and lose data


understand what partition sizes you actually need to do whatever you want to do
spend $20 and get a second ssd and install it, such that you are not dual-booting with grub from one disk.  Rather make the boot choice in the bios as to which disk to boot
a disk can only have one EFI partition, which of course is required for booting

trying to get multiple OS's on one disk all making use of one EFI partition, and not screwing up another OS causing boot problems, is always an issue unless you are an expert.  So much so it is better to just get a second, or third SSD given their low cost now.


having a partition id of 5 extended, indicates it's a dos partition scheme and not GPT.  It is better to have the newer GPT format, so that means you will need to basically copy data from that existing disk and then reformat it and start from scratch, which with linux being a free operating system, is not that big a deal to do if you understand the process and have all your stuff together and understand what's involved.  you didn't elaborate on many other details that are necessary so that's the best advice i can give you.

to back up data, get a 128gb or however large, usb stick from amazon, connect, do

lsblk -o size,model,name,uuid to identify its block device name
if it is /dev/sdd for example, then do

parted /dev/sdd
mklabel gpt
mkpart primary 0% 100%
quit  (or exit I forget which) to get out of parted


mkfs.xfs /dev/sdd1 to make an xfs file system
mkdir /usbstickbackup
mount /dev/sdd1 /usbstickbackup

copy your data
change sdd to sd? depending on however it shows up as for you.



